# Error #2044 on custom flash player using shadowbox

Tags: flash, shadowbox

Hi I'm using shadowbox and I am trying to load my video that has a custom skin. But for some reason it can't find my custom flash player. When I don't use shadowbox I can view the video and the skin shows up. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the shadowbox-flv.js and/or shadowbox-swf.js players as part of your solution? These are needed, I had similar problems, and when I popped those files into my solution it made magic happen.